# Testing console.log inside UseEffect that has dependencies

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, use-effect

I have a simple `App` component. It has two `useEffect` methods. First `useEffect` is ran during the first render and second `useEffect` has dependencies which runs after one of it's dependencies has changed. I am writing unit test to test if `console.log` was called. I know we should not test the business logic in React, but I have a business need which needs me to test this.

// App.tsx

```
function App() {
  const [user, setUser] = useState('')

  useEffect(() => {
    setup()
  }, [])

  useEffect(()=> {
   if(user){
      console.log("UserId set")
    }
  }, [user])

  const setup = async () => {
    console.log('Inside Setup!')
    const response = await getData()
    const userId = response.data.userId
    setUser(userId)
  }

  async function getData() {
    return await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1');
  }

  return (
    <>{!user ? <div>Loading..</div> : <div>It has loaded with {user}</div>}</>
  )
}
```

Unit Test :

```
jest.spyOn(global.console, "log");
describe("test", () => {
  it("mounts", () => {
    mount(<App />);
  });

  it("calls console.log with Inside setup", () => {
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Inside Setup!"); // passes
  });

  it("calls userId set", () => {
    expect(console.log).toHaveBeenCalledWith("UserId set"); // fails with Expected: "UserId set"
    //   Received: "Inside Setup!"
  });
});
```

Any suggestions, how to get console.log("Inside Setup!") working?
Sandbox link for the App : [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-q82ikg?file=/src/Example.test.js)

PS: Tests are working in local, but it isn't working in sandbox

Comment: The reason why it receives "Inside Setup!" could be because its the first console.log() so your test stops after receiving wrong one on first time. Can you try with `toHaveBeenLastCalledWith` method? https://jestjs.io/docs/expect#tohavebeenlastcalledwitharg1-arg2-

Comment: I tried ```expect(console.log).toHaveBeenLastCalledWith('UserId set')```, still gives the same response

Comment: I tried your example,  works for me with method `toHaveBeenLastCalledWith` . Passes all 3 tests. Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hooks-playground-forked-ty026w?file=/src/Example.test.js

Comment: What do you mean by "falls back to previous console.log"? If you mean its not passing; it might have to do with network call, state setting etc taking time and test already ending before that. Try `waitFor` with something like 4 seconds to see if thats case.

Comment: https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-async/#waitfor